# Guice Inject Field in class NullPointerException, circular dependency issue introduced

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, guice

I need to use create a singleton in Guice defined in separate library.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Operator {

    @NonNull private final Catalog catalog;

    @Inject private Evaluator evaluator;
 ...
}
```

One of the problem is that this class introduces circular dependency, Evaluator -> Operator -> Evaluator. I know it is not a good design, but is consumed by other packages, there is no easy way to change it. This library has the beans created using Spring framework, where this circular dependency could be handled.

Now I need to create an instance of the Operator in a service based on Guice, I have created the singleton Evaluator in the service, but it was not able to inject the singleton into the Operator.

```
@Provides @Singleton
public Operator operator(final Catalog catalog) 
{
    return new Operator(catalog);
}

@Provides @Singleton
public Evaluator evaluator(final Operator operator) {
    return new Evaluator(operator);
}
```

Since the Operator class is being used for other services based on Spring framework, I would prefer not to change it. What can I do to make the Guice able to inject the Evaluator into Operator?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Circular dependencies can be resolved by breaking up your components in a more atomic way, or finding a more specific component to depend on. A common problem is a dependency on Application. When your component depends on Application it’s saying that it needs a complete application to do its job; typically that’s not the case. Your dependencies should be on more specific components (e.g. Environment) that have the specific functionality you need. As a last resort you can work around the problem by injecting a Provider<Application>.

Comment: @Tehmina Yeah, the problem is that this component is shared by two services, one using Spring, other using Guice. Spring one is working fine, but Guice one could not inject dependencies. Could you please give a little more information about Provider? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this circular dependency case, Guice is not smart enough to help injecting dependencies, you can specifically ask Guice to inject dependencies for this class.

```
@Provides @Singleton
public Operator operator(final Catalog catalog) 
{
    return new Operator(catalog);
}
```

And then `injector.injectMembers(injector.getInstance(Operator.class))` would help inject the required dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope it will help you.

```
public class Evaluator {
  @Inject public Evaluator(Operator op) {
    // ...
  }
}
public class Operator {
  @Inject public Operator(map m) {
    // ...
  }
}
public class map {
  @Inject public map(Provider<Evaluator> EvaluatorProvider) {
    // ...
  }
}
```